# UIprogressview bar using multiple colors based on progress and condition

Tags: swift, uiprogressview

I am currently working on a quiz based iOS application. I wanted to add a progress bar that changed colors based on if the question was answered correctly or incorrectly. Based on if it was answered correctly or incorrectly, I want only that interval to change to green/red, not the whole bar. I have 50 intervals for the progress bar. Everything I have tried has resulted in the whole bar changing color instead of just the interval. I am pretty new to iOS development still and am struggling to figure this out.

```
let progress = Progress(totalUnitCount: 50)

challengeProgressBar.progress = 0.0
progress.completedUnitCount = 0

for i in 0..<index {
    progress.completedUnitCount += 1 
    challengeProgressBar.setProgress(Float(self.progress.fractionCompleted), animated: true)

    if (selectedAnswer[i] == Answers[i]){
        challengeProgressBar.progressTintColor = UIColor.green
    } else {
        challengeProgressBar.progressTintColor = UIColor.red
    }
}
```

The result I get is the very last color the loop produced. The whole bar is either red or green.

Answer (score 0):

With UIProgressView you can change color only for for filled part of view and color for not filled part.

You need to create custom progress bar by inheriting UIView/UIControl. That way you can achieve needed for you result.